# TypeScript optional in class constructor

Tags: typescript

Currently learning TypeScript. I have a class:

```
class ComicBookCharacter {
  protected secretIdentity?: string;
  alias: string;
  health: number;
  strength: number;


  constructor({ alias, health, strength, secretIdentity }) {
    this.alias = alias;
    this.health = health;
    this.strength = strength;
    this.secretIdentity = secretIdentity;
  }
}

class SuperHero extends ComicBookCharacter {
  getIdentity() {
    console.log(`${this.alias} secret name is ${this.secretIdentity}`)
  }
}

const superman = new ComicBookCharacter({
  alias: 'Superman',
  health: 300,
  strength: 60,
  secretIdentity: undefined,
});
```

I'm wondering if I have to pass `undefined` when creating an instance of a class if I made one of the properties optional (like the `secretIdentity` here);

Removing `secretIdentity: undefined` gets me a compiler error.

**Edit:**

After the solution that Shift 'N Tab gave below, I did some more research and you can also specify the constructor like this:

```
constructor(fields: Partial<ComicBookCharacter> & {
  mothersName?: string,
  secretIdentity?: string,
}) {
  Object.assign(this, fields);
}
```

And as Shift 'N Tab wrote in the comment below, do not forget to add `"strictPropertyInitialization": true` in `tsconfig` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna make an object argument in the constructor you can do that by [Object destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) approach.

```
class ComicBookCharacter{
    secretIdentity?: string;
    alias: string = '';
    health: number = 0;
    strength: number = 0;

    constructor(character: { alias: string, health : number, strength : number, secretIdentity?: string }) {
        Object.assign(this, character);
    }

}
```

Comment: But is there a way to do it when still passing an object to the constructor? I find it more clear when it comes to code readability.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That’s really helpful!

Comment: Just wanted to say once again that this is a really clean way to do this. One thing that pops up in my editor is that it complains the following: `Property alias has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor`. The same is with `health` and `strenth`

Comment: I also found that it can be done with `character: Partial<ComicBookCharacter>`, but then you have to specify those optional fields using `& { secretIdentity?: string }`. I added the edit to my original post so it can maybe help some people :)

Comment: First that is wrong declaring `Partial<Class>` makes all of the constructor parameters **optional**. there is no use of `& { secretIdentity?: string }`. Secondly you are forcing to use a protected field in your initialization, it is suppose to be accessible inside of a class or of a derived class, better to remove the protected keyword from the constructor if you plan to make it public during initialization.

Comment: a work around to your linting error is to make `"strictPropertyInitialization": true,` from your tsconfig or do it safe by assigning manually each property in the constructor class or make a default property value in each declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set secret identity to an empty string in the constructor ( secretIdentity = ‘’ ).